# Burned Cookies - Now what?

Tags: baking

I made Cookies and they are burned at the bottom.

What can I do to remove the burned layer without destroying the cookies and keeping as much as possible from the good parts?

I was thinking of sand paper but I fear this leaves a taste from the "sand" and may be even not healthy.

Comment: If they're not crisp cookies, you might be able to slice off the bottom ... you could then make a filling and use two tops to make a sandwich if you wanted to mask what you did.  If they're crispy or otherwise brittle, that won't work, though.

Comment: Find a friend who like burnt cookies. Surprisingly, they exist.

Comment: Did you taste them? If they're not badly burnt, they might still taste OK. If they are badly burnt, you probably can't rescue them by removing the burnt bits.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: The bottm layer leaves a bad taste. If removed, it is still a fine cookie.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First off, do not use sand paper. The sandpaper grit will wear off over use (which is it's function) and possibly remain in the dough. You don't want anyone eating sand paper grit, and I'm not even sure what it would do. It might even be a hospital-level problem if the grit gets embedded in any digestive tract tissues and causes inflammation. Ugg. Please don't.

If you have a mandolin slicer and the cookies are soft enough, you could set it up on a very thin setting and slide the cookies across the bottom, shaving off a tiny bit.

I like the sandwich idea above.

Answer (score 10):

I'd take a different approach entirely. Throw out the cookies, or at least don't eat them. Compost them, or build a cookie fort for small mammals, or make something decorative, or play cookie frisbee (probably outdoors). Use your imagination.

Consider this failure a learning experience – remember to *actually learn* from it – and try again.

Answer (score 4):

Take a sharp knife and scrape it off.

Answer (score 4):

Easy: cheese grater. Cleans off the bottoms flawlessly!

Answer (score 2):

do what you would do with sand paper but with the edge of a blade at 90°. i sometimes do that in toasts.

EDIT: agree with both comments below :)

Comment: Edge actually at 90° would just wear the blade.  You want it at a slight incline at least.

Comment: @JoeM A butter knife works fine for cleaning up slightly burnt toast: there's no need to use a sharp knife.

Comment: Oh, no disagreement there.  But you can wear the blade of a butterknife as well :)  (Admittedly, that might make it sharper...)

Comment: If a cookie can be used as a whetstone, it is probably beyond direct culinary use.

Answer (score 2):

Place the cookies in an airtight tupperware container with several slices of bread spread over them. The cookies will suck the moisture from the bread and soften up. The time it will take to work can be anywhere from an afternoon, or overnight. It just depends on how hard the cookies are.

I usually do this with just one or two slices of bread to keep cookies from going stale. But I have managed to save some dry cookies by using more bread slices. I can't say it will do anything for the burnt taste, but at least you'll be able to either chew them (or cut the bottoms off).

Answer (score 1):

When that happens with toast I just use a dull knife to scrap the burnt part off.

The thing about baking is most items are to be baked in the middle of the even so there is even heat all around. When there are two items on the same shelf just space them equally.

Another thing is to **not** oil the cookie sheet when baking. Breads need spray coatings but cookies do not.

Answer (score 0):

If you really do not want to toss them, use a clean brick-stone and use as if it were sandpaper. :-)
But not many people have those laying around...

Sandwich idea could work, also like the experience idea and tossing them.

You could always tell your friends that there is hasj stuck to the bottom! :P